# Most efficient algorithm to find integer points within an ellipse

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm trying to find all the integer lattice points within various 3D ellipses.

I would like my program to take an integer N, and count all the lattice points within the ellipses of the form ax^2  + by^2 + cz^2 = n, where a,b,c are fixed integers and n is between 1 and N. This program should then return N tuples of the form (n, numlatticePointsWithinEllipse n).

I'm currently doing it by counting the points on the ellipses ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = m, for m between 0 and n inclusive, and then summing over m. I'm also only looking at x, y and z all positive initially, and then adding in the negatives by permuting their signs later.

Ideally, I'd like to reach numbers of N = 1,000,000+ within the scale of hours

Taking a specific example of x^2 + y^2 + 3z^2 = N, here's the Haskell code I'm currently using:

```
import System.Environment

isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt 0 = 0
isqrt 1 = 1
isqrt n = head $ dropWhile (\x -> x*x > n) $ iterate (\x -> (x + n `div` x) `div` 2) (n `div` 2)

latticePointsWithoutNegatives :: Int -> [[Int]]
latticePointsWithoutNegatives 0 = [[0,0,0]]
latticePointsWithoutNegatives n = [[x,y,z] | x<-[0.. isqrt n], y<- [0.. isqrt (n - x^2)], z<-[max 0 (isqrt ((n-x^2 -y^2) `div` 3))], x^2 +y^2 + z^2 ==n]

latticePoints :: Int -> [[Int]]
latticePoints n = [ zipWith (*) [x1,x2,x3] y |  [x1,x2,x3] <- (latticePointsWithoutNegatives n), y <- [[a,b,c] | a <- (if x1 == 0 then [0] else [-1,1]), b<-(if x2 == 0 then [0] else [-1,1]), c<-(if x3 == 0 then [0] else [-1,1])]]

latticePointsUpTo :: Int -> Int
latticePointsUpTo n = sum [length (latticePoints x) | x<-[0..n]]

listResults :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
listResults n = [(x, latticePointsUpTo x) | x<- [1..n]]

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let cleanArgs = read (head args)
    print (listResults cleanArgs)
```

I've compiled this with

```
ghc -O2 latticePointsTest
```

but using the PowerShell "Measure-Command" command, I get the following results:

```
Measure-Command{./latticePointsTest 10}
TotalMilliseconds : 12.0901

Measure-Command{./latticePointsTest 100}
TotalMilliseconds : 12.0901

 Measure-Command{./latticePointsTest 1000}
TotalMilliseconds : 31120.4503
```

and going any more orders of magnitude up takes us onto the scale of days, rather than hours or minutes.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with the algorithm I'm using? Is there any core reason why my code isn't scaling well? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. I may also want to process the data between "latticePoints" and "latticePointsUpTo", so I can't just rely entirely on clever number theoretic counting techniques - I need the underlying tuples preserved.

Comment: I haven't read the whole question, but why not simply define `isqrt` as `floor . sqrt . fromIntegral`?

Comment: Consider using tools from the [**`arithmoi`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi)

Comment: Surely there is some room for dynamic programming via memorization. If `ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = n/q` exists, then you know that `qax^2 + qby^2 + qcz^2 = n` exists. This multiplicity memorization technique will work for all numbers `q` in the set `[2..sqrt n]`. Efficient optimizations will likely devolve into application of number theory theorems. This might be better received on math.SE.

Comment: @Jubobs Because for a square number, sqrt may give a result slightly less than a integer, and then floor would round it down to the number below. Of course, you could put in a guard to check if it's doing this or not, but I feel happier keeping everything as an integer.

Comment: @recursion.ninja That's a good technique, and it would certainly generate a lot of answers, but it may be possible that there are solutions a,b,c to a^2 +b^2 + c^2 = n, with composite n, where a,b,c have no common factor. Some equations you can show ARE multiplicative in this sense, so you only need to worry about the case where n is a prime power, but I'm not sure it's obvious for a general ellipse.

Comment: @user1440894 See my comments about `floor` and `sqrt` at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things I would try:

`isqrt` is not efficient for the range of values you are working work. Simply use the floating point `sqrt` function:

```
isqrt = floor $ sqrt ((fromIntegral n) :: Double)
```

Alternatively, instead of computing integer square roots, use logic like this in your list comprehensions:

```
x <- takeWhile (\x -> x*x <= n) [0..],
y <- takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= n - x*x) [0..]
```

Also, I would use expressions like `x*x` instead of `x^2`.

Finally, why not compute the number of solutions with something like this:

```
sols a b c n =
  length [ () | x <- takeWhile (\x -> a*x*x <= n) [0..]
              , y <- takeWhile (\y -> a*x*x+b*y*y <= n) [0..]
              , z <- takeWhile (\z -> a*x*x+b*y*y+c*z*z <= n) [0..]
         ]
```

This does not exactly compute the same answer that you want because it doesn't account for positive and negative solutions, but you could easily modify it to compute your answer. The idea is to use one list comprehension instead of iterating over various values of `n` and summing.

Finally, I think using `floor` and `sqrt` to compute the integral square root is completely safe in this case. This code verifies that the integer square root by sing `sqrt` of (x*x) == x for all x <= 3037000499:

```
testAll :: Int -> IO ()
testAll n =
  print $ head [ (x,a) | x <- [n,n-1 .. 1], let a = floor $ sqrt (fromIntegral (x*x) :: Double), a /= x ]

main = testAll 3037000499
```

Note I am running this on a 64-bit GHC - otherwise just use `Int64` instead of `Int` since Doubles are 64-bit in either case. Takes only a minute or so to verify.

This shows that taking the floor of sqrt y will never result in the wrong answer if y <= 3037000499^2.

Comment: The modification to count both positive and negative solutions is `sum [ (1+signum x)*(1+signum y)*(1+signum z) | ... ]`. There's a pair of 2 solutions when the coordinate isn't 0.

Comment: That looks great - why is it so much quicker though?

Comment: Because your algorithm iterates over the same values of (x,y,z) multiple times. For instance, you look at (0,0,0) n times (when n = 0, n = 1, ...), but you only count it once -  when n = 0.